# Dynamically Filtering Visible Div Elements

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I am trying to only display the divs that are selected in the checkboxes. This is working fine. I want to make it so that every time the user enters a character in the search box, the list of items is check, so if the user enters "div 4" and all divs are checked, then upon entering the "4", all will disappear except for the substring containing 4.

I want to do this with no submit button, dynamically.

How can I do this?

My code so far is like this :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      <!-- 
      function dynamicSearch() {
        document.getElementById('search').value
      }

      function showMe (it, box) { 
        var vis = (box.checked) ? "block" : "none"; 
        document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;
      } 
      //--> 
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label for="search">Search:</label>
      <input type="text" name="search" id="search" onkeyup="dynamicSearch()"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="modtype" value="value1" onclick="showMe('div1', this)" />value1
      <input type="checkbox" name="modtype" value="value2" onclick="showMe('div2', this)" />value2
      <input type="checkbox" name="modtype" value="value3" onclick="showMe('div3', this)" />value3
      <input type="checkbox" name="modtype" value="value4" onclick="showMe('div4', this)" />value4
      <input type="checkbox" name="modtype" value="value5" onclick="showMe('div5', this)" />value5
      <div class="row" id="div1" style="display:none">Show Div 1</div>
      <div class="row" id="div2" style="display:none">Show Div 2</div>
      <div class="row" id="div3" style="display:none">Show Div 3</div>
      <div class="row" id="div4" style="display:none">Show Div 4</div>
      <div class="row" id="div5" style="display:none">Show Div 5</div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: May I suggest changing the title to "Dynamically Filtering Visible Div Elements"

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I just hacked together. It needs fleshing out but I think it shows the basic idea.

```
function dynamicSearch() {
    var val = document.getElementById('search').value;
    if (val == '')
      val = '-1';
    var srch = new RegExp(val, "gi");
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
    for (var idx in els) {
      if (idx != parseInt(idx))
        continue;
      var el = els[idx];
      if (typeof(el.innerHTML) !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(el.innerHTML);
        if (srch.test(el.innerHTML)) {
          el.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          el.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a function, which would watch for `document.getElementById('search').value` and bind this function to `onkeyup` event if the search input element.

Comment: How might I go about doing this? I am kind of confused with where to go from here.

Comment: Updated my code there with what you said, I genuinely have no idea how to integrate it properly though.